# remove bots when finding users

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a function that takes random users from the server, but I wanted to remove the bots, so that the function takes only true users

```
getMember: function (message, toFind = '') {
    toFind = toFind.toLowerCase();

    let target = message.guild.members.cache.get(toFind);

    if (!target && message.mentions.members)
        target = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!target && toFind) {
        target = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => {
            return member.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(toFind) ||
                member.user.tag.toLowerCase().includes(toFind)
        });
    }

    if (!target)
        target = message.member;

    return target;

}
```

Comment: what server it is? what is a shape of data from server (message). what is diffrence in data between users and bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member.user.bot` returns a boolean value representing if the member is a bot or not

you can filter the members collection to not contain bots by doing

```js
let membersNoBots = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot);
```